# Convert Spring XML-based to Java-Based Configuration

Tags: java, xml, spring, configuration, spring-annotations

I try not to using any xml.

```
<bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">

    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="marshaller" ref="jaxbMarshaller"/>
                <property name="unmarshaller" ref="jaxbMarshaller"/>
            </bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

like this one: convert to @Bean

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();

    converters.add(marshallingMessageConverter());
    restTemplate.setMessageConverters(converters);

    return restTemplate;
}
```

Problem here.

```
<bean id="jaxbMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="classesToBeBound">
        <list>
            <value>com.cloudlb.domain.User</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Try to convert "com.cloudlb.domain.User" into Class [] not thing work.

```
@Bean
public MarshallingHttpMessageConverter marshallingMessageConverter() {
    Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();

    //
    List<Class<?>> listClass = new ArrayList<Class<?>>();
    listClass.add(User.class);

    marshaller.setClassesToBeBound((Class<?>[])listClass.toArray());
    // --------------------------------

    return new MarshallingHttpMessageConverter(marshaller, marshaller);
}
```

Error: problem with casting.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: post the error you are getting

Comment: Shouldn't `<list>` be converted to a  `List` rather than an array?

Comment: @Thomas: `<list>` will be coerced to whatever is necessary, e.g. `List`, or array.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
@Bean
public MarshallingHttpMessageConverter marshallingMessageConverter() {
    return new MarshallingHttpMessageConverter(
        jaxb2Marshaller(),
        jaxb2Marshaller()
    );
}

@Bean
public Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller() {
    Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(new Class[]{
               twitter.model.Statuses.class
    });
    return marshaller;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`setClassesToBeBound` takes a vararg list, so you can just do this:

```
Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(User.class);
```