# Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter with jaxb2marshaller

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, configuration

I setup on both client and server to have MarshallingMessageConverter using Jaxb2

Follow from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8717992/convert-spring-xml-based-to-java-based-configuration) question.

This is on server-side:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(marshallingMessageConverter());
    }

    public MarshallingHttpMessageConverter marshallingMessageConverter() {
        return new MarshallingHttpMessageConverter(jaxb2Marshaller(), jaxb2Marshaller());
    }

    public Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(new Class[]{
                User.class
            });
        return marshaller;
    }
}
```

Client-side:

```
@Configuration
public class RESTConfig {

    @Bean
    public MarshallingHttpMessageConverter marshallingMessageConverter() {
        return new MarshallingHttpMessageConverter(jaxb2Marshaller(), jaxb2Marshaller());
    }

    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(new Class[] {
            User.class
        });
        return marshaller;
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
        //converters.addAll(restTemplate.getMessageConverters());

        converters.add(marshallingMessageConverter());
        restTemplate.setMessageConverters(converters);

        return restTemplate;
    }
}
```

Check on both log got:

```
org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller createJaxbContextFromClasses
INFO: Creating JAXBContext with classes to be bound [class com.cloudlb.model.User]
```

when I try to retrieve User. I got this

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: 
Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [com.cloudlb.model.User] and content type [application/xml]
```

Did I missing something?

I check by retrieve it as String.class and it work fine. Got return in XML file format.

I want to achieve the  XML <--HTTP--> XML <-> Object>

```
User user = restTemplate.getForObject(url, User.class);
```

Edited: This is my Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserServiceController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    public UserServiceController() {}

    @RequestMapping(value="/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public User findUserById(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
        return userService.findById(id);
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How is your User class defined - does it have @XmlRootElement annotation?

Comment: Yes I have. It look like this  
  
`@Entity  
@Table(name = "user")  
@XmlRootElement(name = "user")  
public class User implements Serializable { ... }`

Comment: Can we see your Controller which handles your request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I configured this I defined a ContentNegotiatingViewResolver as follows:

```
@Bean
public ContentNegotiatingViewResolver contentNegotiatingViewResolver() {
    ContentNegotiatingViewResolver resolver = new ContentNegotiatingViewResolver();
    Map<String, String> mediaTypes = new HashMap<String, String>();
    mediaTypes.put("xml", "application/xml");
    resolver.setMediaTypes(mediaTypes);

    List<ViewResolver> viewResolvers = new ArrayList<ViewResolver>();
    viewResolvers.add(new BeanNameViewResolver());

    resolver.setViewResolvers(viewResolvers);

    return resolver;
}
```

and then from my Controller I returned:

```
return new ModelAndView("spotView", "spot", spot);
```

and then in my config I defined a bean with the same name as the view returned from the controller (because I'm using a BeanName resolver):

```
@Bean
public MarshallingView spotView() {
    return new MarshallingView(jaxbMarshaller());
}
```

Comment: What if my controller is return as Object(User)? Is this can be achieve?

Comment: You can just return a ModelAndView passing in your User. Then define a bean called userView as in my example.

Comment: Its got 406 HTTP ERROR. I figure it out that I forget to put `@XmlRootElement` as @Grzegorz Grzybez mention in User domain object in client side. I put only on server-side