# How to initialize JAXB context object and instance class file in spring application.properties file?

Tags: xml, spring, jaxb, apache-camel

I have to read multiple **xml** files using **Apache camel** in spring application then unmarshalling that **xml** file using **JAXB** context object.

But the program takes lot of time for creating **JAXB** context object for each and every time reading new file and calling unmarshaller bean.

I don't need to recreate **JAXB** context object each and every time.

How to initialize **JAXB** Context object and jaxb instance (class file) in application.properties ?

Comment: (i think) there are no "out-of-the-box" spring(-boot) properties for jaxb, but this is the [current spring - jaxb reference doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#oxm-jaxb) (with xml configuration), here [a java-config sample ;)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44678803/592355) ..if "jaxb is not a must", you can consider the "jackson"/spring-boot alternatives... ..and if the problem is not in "context creation", but in (xml)"file size" ...then you'd have to consider [tag:jaxp].

Comment: [see..](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html), nothing found for "jaxb"...nor "oxm" ...nor "marsh" ..but a lot of "spring.jackson*"

Comment: How are you using those 'xml' files in Camel? Perhaps posting the route would be helpful. Include your camel version too.